# changing type in getter - sequelize with graphql

Tags: javascript, json, sequelize.js, graphql, getter

I'm trying to stringify an array as I save it to my mysql database, and parse it when I retrieve it, but I'm getting "String cannot represent an array". Is changing the type in a getter possible with sequelize and if so how would it be done?

```
choices: {
  type:Sequelize.TEXT,
  get(){
    var val = this.getDataValue('choices');
    return val ? JSON.parse(val):null;
  },
  set(val){
    if(val && typeof(val)!=='string'){
      val = JSON.stringify(val);
    }
    this.setDataValue('choices',val);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a problem with sequelize or mysql. This was a problem with my GraphQL mutation where I had to override a type

```
import { attributeFields } from "graphql-sequelize";
import { GraphQLList, GraphQLString } from "graphql";
import { Question } from "../schemas/Question";
import ResponsePayload from "../schemas/ResponsePayload";
import _ from "lodash";

var base = _.assign(attributeFields(sequelize.models.question, {
  exclude: ["id", "createdAt", "updatedAt"]
}), { choices: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) }});

const CreateQuestion = {
  type: ResponsePayload,
  args: base,
  resolve: ...
};

export { CreateQuestion };
```

specifically I had to change

```
var base = attributeFields(sequelize.models.question, {
  exclude: ["id", "createdAt", "updatedAt"]
});
```

to

```
var base = _.assign(attributeFields(sequelize.models.question, {
  exclude: ["id", "createdAt", "updatedAt"]
}), { choices: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) }});
```

This overrides the type of choices, which is defined as a String in the sequelize model, but needs to be an array as far as GraphQL is concerned.